# Taylor's Series with Fibonacci coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we get a function whose infinite series is in the form:
$g(z) = 1 + z + 2z^2 + 3z^3 + 5z^4 + 8z^5 + 13z^6 + ... $
Or
$f(z) = g(z)-1 = z + 2z^2 + 3z^3 + 5z^4 + 8z^5 + 13z^6 + ...$

where $z$ is a complex number and the coefficients are the terms of the popular Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: It is well known and it evaluates to $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Power_series